# Android - compile error when implementing ServiceConnection

Tags: android, android-billing

I am working on adding in-app billing and working from [this official documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

And I am on the section `Binding to IInAppBillingService`

Here is my code:

```
public class CommunityActivity extends BaseActivity implements ServiceConnection
{   
    ArrayAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
    Dialog dialog;
    ArrayList<ChatMessage> chat = new ArrayList <ChatMessage>( );       

    IInAppBillingService mService;

    ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
           @Override
           public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
               mService = null;
           }

           @Override
           public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, 
              IBinder service) {
               mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
           }
        };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "8CA5LTZ5M73EG8R35SXG");

        setContentView(R.layout.community);

        bindService(new 
                Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                        mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

But I get compile errors saying I have to implement the onServiceConnected and onServiceDisconnected methods.  But I thought I already added them in a way that the example suggested.

Where did I go wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you have declared your class as follows

`public class CommunityActivity extends BaseActivity implements ServiceConnection`

now compiler expects that u have these two functions `onServiceConnected` and `on ServiceDisconnected` implemented in `CommunityActivity`. but it cannot find them in this class.

remove this `implements ServiceConnection` and code should compile successfully.

Comment: thanks, but it says in that section that I should implement that ServiceConnection  interface. Or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: you are already implementing the interface here `ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection(){ .... }` and `mServiceConn` is basically that you are already using in `bindService()` . you don't need `implements ServiceConnection` in the class definition anymore .